# lftp crawl for any newly created files and download them

Tags: bash, command, lftp

I have just mirrored a remote webserver using `lftp`'s `mirror` command. However, the webserver updates regularly with newly created files, although it does not update any already existing ones. How can I use `lftp` to download all newly created files on the remote webserver into their respective paths?